# Mock an object in Espresso

Tags: android, testing, mocking, android-espresso

Today I started to use `Espresso` to test an `Activity`, I am practical with `Junit` tests but do not understand how to mock, I have the line cashPeriod that obviously gives me a `NPE` when I try to launch the activity with Espresso

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //no layout preview possible
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_combi_book_balance)
    title = getString(R.string.balance_details)
    setupActionBarWithHomeEnabled(true)

    val cashPeriod: CashPeriod = intent.extras.getParcelable(PERIOD_OBJECT_EXTRA)
    val sections = showList(cashPeriod)
    setAdapter(sections)
}
```

and my Espresso test is

```
@Test
    fun appLaunchesSuccessfully() {
        ActivityScenario.launch(CombiBookBalanceDetailActivity::class.java)
    }
```

Now if I stub the cashPeriod in the onCreate giving some hardcoded values, the test passes, but I need to do that in the test class of course

**How can I mock the line val cashPeriod: CashPeriod = intent.extras.getParcelable(PERIOD_OBJECT_EXTRA) in my espresso test?** Is different by Junit, where I use Mockito/mockito-kotlin/mockk and give a behaviour with `when /// return //that`

Comment: See here: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ActivityTestRule` 
See [this](https://github.com/barend/android-espresso-intent-sample/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/nl/garvelink/blog/espressointentsample/MainActivityLaunchIntentTest.java)

Comment: thank you for your help but does not help your example

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but maybe this is what you were looking for. You can add this inside your espresso test.

```
 @Test fun testName() {
    val intent = Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), CombiBookBalanceDetailActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(PERIOD_OBJECT_EXTRA, "some test value")
    val scenario = launchActivity<CombiBookBalanceDetailActivity>(intent)
}
```